# Proper way to write async using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, asynchronous, csvhelper

Can someone tell me how to use the **CsvWriter** to write a list of objects without blocking? It's not obvious to me.

Do I need first to call **WriteRecords()** and after this **FlushAsync()** or should I write each object one by one using **NextRecordAsync()**?

Actually, I would expect to use a dedicated method, but it's not there:

```
public Task WriteRecordsAsync(...);
```

Comment: As of 1-16-2020, version 13.0.0, there is now a dedicated method for that: `Task CsvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> records)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WriteRecords` will call `NextRecord` for you, since it's writing multiple. Because of this, you need to write the records manually. It's only a couple more lines.

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    csv.WriteRecord(record);
    await csv.NextRecordAsync();
}
```

The reason there is no `WriteRecordsAsync` is because it's not required. It would basically be just duplicating most of the code in the library, just to save a few lines. The only part that has low level need for `async` in the system is writing to the `TextWriter`, so as little as possible above it is `async` also.

Comment: I don't like the idea to us so many continuations, but maybe it doesn't matter. Would it also be non blocking if I would instead use WriteRecords() and FlushAsync() afterwards? I'm not sure because I haven't diggt deep enough into the source code.  I can imagine that at some point a blocking IO operation will be called inside the library if you provide to many records at once.

Comment: @al-bex yes, I occasionally get `InvalidOperationException: The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream.` when using the async version of `NextRecord`